# Building a searchbar into an Eclipse View Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm looking for some ideas/resources on how to approach building a search bar on top of an existing view eclipse plugin. I want something similar to what the Task List view in eclipse has:

http://help.targetprocess.com/images/integration_api/eclipse3.png?1337868355

The view I want to build this on is just a simple list of objects, basically exactly like the simple view tutorials eclipse PDE provides. Nothing complicated.

I've searched around and there doesn't seem to be much information on this. If anyone could give me some guidance on how to start, that would be great.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create an [SWT Text component](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Text.html) with style [SEARCH](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/SWT.html#SEARCH). There is an [SWT snippet](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet309.java?view=co) showing the applicable style combinations. That gives you the input field with the icon and some message, but you still have to implement the necessary filtering on the list yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I understand how to build searchbars using the Eclipse SWT, I guess my main problem is I do not know how to integrate that into a TableViewer from a view plugin. Like, in my createPartControl method, I'm not sure how to get a GridLayout to display that can handle both the Table view as well as this new input field I want.

Comment: There are two options: Either configure the gridlayout with some parameters for each component as in step 3 of http://www.devx.com/opensource/Article/21562/1954 (if you want all components in that one gridlayout) or you instead nest multiple SWT composite components into each other and all of those can then have their own layout and contain only some of your widgets (e.g. one composite holding the text field, one holding the table view).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will find anything written about doing this as it's pretty low level. What I would do is just to look at the source code of the thing that has what you want. And you can steal it as you like (provided you follow the EPL rules).