# Implement "search" feature in an eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working on developing an eclipse plugin with a tree view. I want to implement a search bar on top of the view that would allow me to search the text I am looking for in the tree view. I am unable to find a good article/example for the same. Here are some of the relevant questions I referred on stackOverflow:
[Search-Plugin for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219441/search-plugin-for-eclipse) and
[Building a searchbar into an Eclipse View Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463238/building-a-searchbar-into-an-eclipse-view-plugin)

Can someone please suggest me a good example to start with?

Thanks

Comment: `org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.FilteredTree` might help, this is what many Eclipse dialogs such as the Preferences dialog use.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I see a blog on using filtered trees. Will post again if I find a good example that works.

Comment: http://blog.vogella.com/2009/06/24/eclipse-filteredtree/ is a good start. For me this didn't work well, since I was using another tree implementation already. But you can implement a Combo field and add a KeyAdapter (KeyListener).

Answer (score 2):

http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/10/26/filtering-tables-in-swtjface/

and http://blog.vogella.com/2009/06/24/eclipse-filteredtree/ were very useful tutorials for me. Thanks for the suggestions. My plugin has a search feature now! :)

Comment: Can you post a link to your plugin? (if it's open source)